# how to run a shell script on remote using salt-ssh

Tags: salt-stack, remote-execution

my web server generates a shell script with more than 100 lines of code based on complex user selections. I need to orchestrate this over several machines using salt-ssh. what I need is to copy this shell script to remote and execute it from there for all devices. how to achieve this with `salt-ssh` ?. I can not install minions on the remote device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as with normal minion. Write a state...

```
add script:
    file.managed:
    - name: file.sh
    - source: /path/to/file.sh

run script:
    cmd.run:
    - name: file.sh
```

...and apply it

`salt-ssh 'minions*' state.apply mystate.sls`